# Force asyncio to emit exception logs whether or not task is awaited

Tags: python-asyncio

(This is a follow-up question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60287285/starlette-asyncio-create-task-doesnt-log-error-if-task-object-is-stored-in/60294819?noredirect=1#comment106656879_60294819).)

---

The [docs for asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#detect-never-retrieved-exceptions) say:

> If a Future.set_exception() is called but the Future object is never awaited on, the exception would never be propagated to the user code. In this case, asyncio would emit a log message when the Future object is garbage collected.

---

I want to know whether there's any way to make python forcefully log exceptions regardless of :

1. Whether or not I awaited the task
2. Whether or not the task is garbage collected

---

Basically, I want the ability to fire and forget some background tasks from anywhere in my code, and not worry about `await`-ing them all the time.

My first-hand async experience was in dart, which does not seem to suffer from this issue.

(Plus, this blatantly violates [the zen of python #10](https://zen-of-python.info/errors-should-never-pass-silently.html#10)).

Answer (score 1):

> Basically, I want the ability to fire and forget some background tasks from anywhere in my code, and not worry about `await`-ing them all the time.

If you control the coroutines, the most straightforward way is for the coroutine itself to catch and log the errors. You can automate it using a decorator like this:

```py
def log_exceptions(fn):
    async def run_with_log(*args, **kwds):
        try:
            return await fn(*args, **kwds)
        except Exception as e:
            print "Exception in %s: %s" % (fn.__name__, e)
    return run_with_log
```

Now, decorating your top-level coroutines with `@log_exceptions` will give you the requested behavior.

I am not aware of an asyncio switch that does this by default because it would violate the contract of `Task` (which captures both the return value and the exception raised by the coroutine, if any).

> (Plus, this blatantly violates the zen of python #10).

The [trio](https://github.com/python-trio/trio) library offers a different take on this, in the form of [nurseries](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference-core.html#nurseries-and-spawning), which guarantee not only that the exception will be logged, but that it will be re-raised at a predictable place.

Comment: Thanks. There's also an alternative answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60301541/7061265

Comment: Your solution seems to suffer from not being able to catch the original exception in case you do decide to await the task.

Comment: @DevAggarwal I didn't expect that you'd require _both_ logging and accessing the original exception, but if that's the requirement, then the other answer is an excellent solution.