# asyncio.Queue producer-consumer flow cannot handle exception when consumers contain in a named list

Tags: python, asynchronous, exception, queue, python-asyncio

Working on a producer-consumer flow based on the `asyncio.Queue`.
Codes below take reference from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52615705) and this [blog](https://www.roguelynn.com/words/asyncio-exception-handling/).

```py
import asyncio

async def produce(q: asyncio.Queue, t):
    asyncio.create_task(q.put(t))
    print(f'Produced {t}')

async def consume(q: asyncio.Queue):
    while True:
        res = await q.get()
        if res > 2:
            print(f'Cannot consume {res}')
            raise ValueError(f'{res} too big')
        print(f'Consumed {res}')
        q.task_done()

async def shutdown(loop, signal=None):
    tasks = [t for t in asyncio.all_tasks() if t is not asyncio.current_task()]
    print(f"Cancelling {len(tasks)} outstanding tasks")
    [task.cancel() for task in tasks]

def handle_exception(loop, context):
    msg = context.get("exception", context["message"])
    print(f"Caught exception: {msg}")
    asyncio.create_task(shutdown(loop))

async def main():
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.set_exception_handler(handle_exception)

    [asyncio.create_task(consume(queue)) for _ in range(1)]
    # consumers = [asyncio.create_task(consume(queue)) for _ in range(1)]

    try:
        for i in range(6):
            await asyncio.create_task(produce(queue, i))
        await queue.join()
    except asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError:
        print('Cancelled')


asyncio.run(main())
```

When wrapping the consumers like above (without a naming list), the output is as expected:

```
Produced 0
Consumed 0
Produced 1
Consumed 1
Produced 2
Consumed 2
Produced 3
Cannot consume 3
Caught exception: 3 too big
Produced 4
Cancelling 2 outstanding tasks
Cancelled
```

But when giving the consumer list a name, which means change the code inside `main()` like this:

```py
async def main():
    # <-- snip -->

    # [asyncio.create_task(consume(queue)) for _ in range(1)]
    consumers = [asyncio.create_task(consume(queue)) for _ in range(1)]

    # <-- snip -->
```

The program gets stuck like this:

```
Produced 0
Consumed 0
Produced 1
Consumed 1
Produced 2
Consumed 2
Produced 3
Cannot consume 3
Produced 4
Produced 5  # <- stuck here, have to manually stop by ^C
```

It seems like the `producer` still keeps producing so that the items in the `queue` keeps growing after the `ValueError` raised. The `handle_exception` never get called. And the program gets stuck at the `await queue.join()`.

But why giving a name to the consumers list would change the behavior of the code? Why the `handle_exception` never get called after consumers list being named?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not about the named list. Your example can be simplified to:

```
asyncio.create_task(consume(queue))
# consumer = asyncio.create_task(consume(queue))
```

The point here is in the `Task` object that the function `create_task` returns. In one case, it is destroyed, but in the other not. Good answers have been given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27299160/13782669) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60294819/13782669)

Comment: Thanks, but why I use a named list is because I actually would create more consumers like `for _ in range(10)` and I wanna cancel all the idle consumers after the `await queue.join()` like this: `for c in consumers: c.cancel()`. 
If the "the exception only gets raised if the Task is destroyed", does that mean that "cancel all tasks" and "handle exceptions if raise" cannot be done both? Since if no exception raised, one should cancel all these idling consumer tasks.

Comment: I think you need to redesign your code, and write coro that starts all consumers and waits it results with `asyncio.wait(..., return_when=FIRST_EXCEPTION)`.

Comment: I found that `await asyncio.wait([queue.join(), *consumers], return_when=asyncio.FIRST_EXCEPTION)` would stuck the program if no exception raised. The reason is simple: `consumers` never complete, and `FIRST_EXCEPTION` is equivalent to `ALL_COMPLETED` when no future raises an exception.
It seems the only way to work around this is to: use `await asyncio.wait([queue.join(), *consumers], return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)`, and check the `done` part if there are any consumers in there like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59629996).

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR Don't use `set_exception_handler` to handle exception in tasks. Instead, add the requisite `try: ... except: ...` in the coroutine itself.

The problem is in the attempt to use [`set_exception_handler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.set_exception_handler) to handle exceptions. That function is a last-ditch attempt to detect an exception that has passed through all the way to the event loop, most likely as the result of a bug in the program. If a callback added by `loop.call_soon` or `loop.call_at` etc. raises an exception (and doesn't catch it), the handler installed by `set_exception_handler` will be consistently invoked.

With a task things are more nuanced: a task drives a coroutine to completion and, once done, stores its *result*, making it available to anyone who awaits the task, to callbacks installed by [`add_done_callback`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.Future.add_done_callback), but also to any call that invokes `result()` on the task. (All this is mandated by the contract of [`Future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.Future), which `Task` is a subclass of.) When the coroutine raises an unhandled exception, this exception is just another result: when someone awaits the task or invokes `result()`, the exception will be (re-)raised then and there.

This leads to the difference between naming and not naming the task objects. If you don't name them, they will be destroyed as soon as the event loop is done executing them. At the point of their destruction, Python will notice that no one has ever accessed their result and will pass it to the exception handler. On the other hand, if you store them in a variable, they won't be destroyed as long as they're referenced by the variable and there will be no reason to call the event loop handler: as far as Python is concerned, you might decide to call `.result()` on the objects at any point, access the exception and handle it as appropriate for your program.

To fix the issue, just handle the exception yourself by adding a `try: ... except: ...` block around the body of the coroutine. If you don't control the coroutine, you can use `add_done_callback()` to detect the exception instead.